# Displaying a simple triangle using OpenGL and SFML

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am playing a bit with OpenGL and SFML. I am a beginner in both of these. I was going through some tutorials and tried myself to adjust them a bit. But I just can't get the following code to work. It should display a white triangle but it displays just black screen. It prints no error messages.

There are a few lines commented out which would use vertex buffer objects instead of vertex arrays which are currently used. But none of these two work.

I guess I must be missing something really simple... but do not know what.

My card says it supports OpenGL3.1, but could that be the source of the problem? When I tried similar example with OpenGL in Qt, it worked fine.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>

bool createShader(GLuint &shaderID, GLenum shaderType, const char* shaderSource)
{
    shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &shaderSource, 0);
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    GLint compileStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);
    if (compileStatus == GL_TRUE)
        return true;

    // log error
    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar* buffer = new GLchar[infoLogLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, infoLogLength, &infoLogLength, buffer);
    std::cerr << buffer << std::endl;
    delete[] buffer;
    return false;
}

bool createShaderProgram(GLuint &programID)
{
    const char *vertexShaderSource =
        "attribute vec2 position;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 0.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    const char *fragmentShaderSource =
        "void main() {\n"
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    GLuint vertexShaderID;
    if (! createShader(vertexShaderID, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource))
        return false;

    GLuint fragmentShaderID;
    if (! createShader(fragmentShaderID, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource))
        return false;

    programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programID);

    GLint linkStatus;
    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
    if (linkStatus == GL_TRUE)
        return true;

    // log error
    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetShaderiv(programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar* buffer = new GLchar[infoLogLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(programID, infoLogLength, &infoLogLength, buffer);
    std::cerr << buffer << std::endl;
    delete[] buffer;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, sf::ContextSettings(32));
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Status: Using GLEW " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << std::endl;

    GLuint programID;
    if (! createShaderProgram(programID))
        exit(1);

    glUseProgram(programID);

    static const GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f
    };
    //GLuint vertexBufferID;
    //glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLint posAttrID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "position");

    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrID, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices); // 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrID);

    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                running = false;
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
            }
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        window.display();
    }

    // release resources...

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Some people below suggest I MUST use VBO and VAO. Is that true? Or is it just optional for better performance? Cannot I send data from normal RAM into glVertexAttribPointer()?

I also tried the code above on a desktop machine supporting OpenGL4.4 (before I tried just a lazy laptop with integrated graphics supporting OpenGL3.1) and the result is: the whole screen is white. Before it was black. Why? I do not get it to be honest.

Comment: VAOs are _not_ a replacement for VBOs. You need _both_ in modern GL.

Comment: I have not used nor mentioned VAO in any way, I know it is something completely different (context handling, binding, unbiding stuff etc.). And I strongly believe I do not need to use VAO at all if I can bind/unbind stuff manually.

Comment: VAOs are required in modern GL. But anyway, vertex arrays are not a replacement for VBOs either, you need to put the vertex arrays into VBOs. Now it is unclear if you intend to use modern GL, and I don't know what context SFML creates by default.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you suggesting that if I used also VAO, then it could work? Well, I am not sure about that because I have seen tutorials which worked even without VAOs. Or do you mean that my SFML uses "old" context that does not support even VBOs?

Comment: A VAO is an OpenGL object that stores the format of your attributes and in which buffer it's data is stored. So a VAO merely references buffer objects. Buffer objects have data storage that contain the data but they do not know anything about that data. So you need both as they have very different functions. And yes, older techniques don't require you to use VAO's or buffers (like glBegin()/glEnd())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks buffers to store your vertex attribute data (just uncomment the buffer section) and a VAO.

### VAO

A VAO is an object that stores the format for every attribute (data type, size etc.) and some information that tells OpenGL where it can find the per-vertex data for it (in which buffer). It also stores the offset into the buffer and stride. It doesn't store the vertex attribute data itself.

You can have multiple VAO's (you create them with glCreateVertexArrays()) and you must first bind one (glBindVertexArray()) before you can use it. Any rendering you do with glDrawArrays() or glDrawElements() (or any variation thereof) and any calls to glVertexAttribPointer() and the likes uses the currently bound VAO.

This is useful if you have multiple meshes with vertex attributes with different formats. You can easily change all that state with a single function call. However, switching VAO's is performance heavy so try to minimize this by storing your meshes with the same attribute format.

### VBO (are just general-purpose buffers)

The VBO itself doesn't know any of this information. It's just a general purpose buffer and it only knows how much data it contains and it has a usage hint (STATIC_DRAW etc.).

All in all, your code needs just two changes:
uncomment the buffer section and create and bind a VAO before calling glVertexAttribPointer(). Note that the info you supply with glBufferData() is not part of VAO state.

**Edit1:**
In your vertex shader you output `vec4(position, 0.0, 0.0)` via `gl_Position` with the w component being 0. w should always be one. You should change it to `vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it seems that I misunderstood the concept of VAO. According to some tutorials I got the impression that you need only bind VAOs if you want to store/restore the bind/unbind state of buffers. But after I dug deeper into this, it seems that I can only use direct access to a memory array (as in my code), i.e. without VBO and VAO, in something called "core profile" OpenGL (I assume this means the same as "old" OpenGL). Is that right? Tonight I will try uncommenting VBO and add VAO and let you know how it worked.

Comment: I uncommented the lines with VBO and `// 0);`. Then I added `glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);  glBindVertexArray(vao);  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`... But no change. Did I forgot about something? Could you suggest how to incorporate VAO into this simple example?

Comment: With 'direct access to a memory array', are you referring to the fact that glVertexAttribPointer() used to supply a pointer to client-side memory instead of just an offset into a buffer? In that case, yes, that function only does that in older versions of ogl. A core profile is not an old OpenGL version. It's the opposite. It means that your context will, for a given ogl version, only expose functions that are 'up-to-date' or deprecated but not removed. A compatibility profile will also expose all those removed functions (old ogl). Tip, check out: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/

Comment: I see, my mistake about the core profile. I now found a paragraph in SFML docs: "OpenGL versions above 3.0 are supported by SFML (as long as your graphics driver can handle them), but you can't set flags for now. This means that you can't create debug or forward compatible contexts; in fact SFML automatically creates contexts with the "compatibility" flag, because it uses deprecated functions internally. This should be improved soon, and flags will then be exposed in the public API. "

Seems that this might be the cause. It seems that SFML does not create context with core profile.

Comment: `glEnableClientState()` is a very old function from OpenGL 2. You shouldn't use it (yes, I know `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` sound like it has something to do with all this but it doesn't  :p). I don't know if this is causing trouble or not but I suggest you remove it. A compatibility context of a high enough version should work just fine. Core just means that old stuff is removed and compatibility means that you can use both new stuff and old stuff.

Comment: Updated my answer with another problem I found

Comment: YES, your Edit1 paragraph is what makes it work! With all the troubles about VBO and VAO I overlooked the last component of the position. My simple program works and I can dive into some more serious stuff. And as a side effect I learned more about VAO, core profile etc... Thank you so much! :)